# how to add tab content in seperate new tab in details page?

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, tabs

On my product details page I have three tabs, with the help of the following code:

```
 <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
            <?php  
                    if(trim($html)=="") continue;           
            ?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The tab contents are like:

[image]

Now I want to **create a new and separate product-collateral tab** near the above mentioned tabs.

When I use the below line in `catalog.xml` it is adding the tab content to the same tab.

```
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
```

I want to create a separate tab like the above one, not add to the existing one.

How can this be done?

Comment: do you want to duplicate Description tab's content to New tab ?

Comment: yes I want to do it that way.

Comment: I want to duplicate the entire tab ( create a tab similar to the above) with different content.

Comment: This answer is already given below by Raphael

Comment: want to add whole new `product-collateral` block with tab(s) ?

Comment: His answer adds a tab additional to those three tab. I want to create a new tab seperately. I dont want to add to those existing tab.

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to create a new `product-collateral` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create new Group for this. Add this to `<catalog_product_view>` handle.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description.sec" as="description_sec" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info_sec</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes.sec" as="additional_sec" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info_sec</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

Note, I have created a new group, named , `detailed_info_sec`, with two tabs, **Description** and **Additional Information**, you can add OR edit them as per your requirement.

To show this to frontend, add this block of code, to `view.phtml`

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info_sec', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs-sec" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: yes It worked.This is exactly what I want. Thank you so much @Anil Suthar. Do We need to change the name similar to `detailed_info` to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to add the following code to `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml` :

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="product.tab.fourth" as="fourth_tab" template="path/to/your/template.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Fourth Tab</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

You will need to create the template to display the content: `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/path/to/your/template.phtml`

And also replace the value under the `setTitle` tag with the name you want to give to your tab.

Comment: I think  you are giving me answer to add the fourth tab as additional tab to that already present three tabs. I want to display the `fourth_tab` in a seperate tab.